# Why is there only one plain associative operad?

Tags: category-theory

I'm really confused by $Assoc$ as a single plain operad. Yes I know that it is generated by a binary operation, $\Theta$ with the relation $\Theta\cdot(\Theta\otimes 1) =\Theta\cdot(1\otimes\Theta)$.

Why is there only one associative plain operad when we can have numerous associative binary operation $\Theta$? Is it because as plain operads they are all isomorphic anyway hence we declare that only one of them effectively exists?

Edited: I guess my own explanation is likely correct. We don't consider isomorphic groups or other isomorphic algebraic objects separate entities. Why shall we make an exception for operads?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. If the question is "I know a whole lot of associative algebras that are not isomorphic, so why is there a unique associative operads ?" then the answer is: every such associative algebras are _algebras_ over $\mathsf{Assoc}$; the operation $\Theta$ of $\mathsf{Assoc}$ _encodes_ the associativity law that a binary operation might follow, but does not tell anything else about it. [...]

Comment: [...] If the question is "Am I allowed to call $\mathsf{Assoc}$ an operad that is isomorphic to the one with $\Theta$?", then my answer would be: do you hesitate to call $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ the group $\{-1,+1\}$ ?

Comment: @Pece Yep. That's just emotional attachment to having so many associative algebras at work. I have changed my mind.